# xmlsec library version mismatch Ubunto 20.04

Tags: django, linux, ubuntu, lxml, xmlsec

Currently installed:

1. xmlsec: 1.3.13
2. lxml:4.9.1

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Traceback (most recent call last):

from onelogin.saml2.auth import OneLogin_Saml2_Auth

File "/home/vboxuser/Desktop/web/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onelogin/saml2/auth.py", line 14, in \<module\>

import xmlsec

xmlsec.Error: (19, 'xmlsec library version mismatch.')
```

I have tried reinstalling the packages but it didn't work.

Comment: And how did you install which of the libraries?

Comment: @Khaled did you managed to solve the issue?